# What's the reason of App crashing with Crashed: com.apple.main-thread on firstIndex(where:)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am getting a **crash** report in **Crashlytics** as below.

I tried a lot of ways generating this crash, but I am not able to generate this crash

```
   Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
    0  MyApp                          0x1010d4b1c specialized Collection.firstIndex(where:) + 2433 (MyViewController.swift:2433)
    1  MyApp                          0x101094ee4 MyViewController.collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:) + 4307881700 (<compiler-generated>:4307881700)
    2  MyApp                          0x1010c2df4 @objc MyViewController.collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:) + 4308069876
    3  UIKitCore                      0x1aba8ae74 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:notify:] + 424
    4  UIKitCore                      0x1aba8f6f0 -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 4352
    5  UIKitCore                      0x1aba93fbc -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 320
    6  UIKitCore                      0x1ac6bc17c -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2140
    7  QuartzCore                     0x1aec242c0 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 284
    8  QuartzCore                     0x1aec2a43c CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 480
    9  QuartzCore                     0x1aec35140 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 136
    10 QuartzCore                     0x1aeb7d884 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double) + 304
    11 QuartzCore                     0x1aeba7574 CA::Transaction::commit() + 676
    12 QuartzCore                     0x1aeba7f68 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 92
    13 CoreFoundation                 0x1a811de68 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
    14 CoreFoundation                 0x1a8118d54 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 416
    15 CoreFoundation                 0x1a8119320 __CFRunLoopRun + 1308
    16 CoreFoundation                 0x1a8118adc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
    17 GraphicsServices               0x1b20b9328 GSEventRunModal + 104
    18 UIKitCore                      0x1ac22663c UIApplicationMain + 1936
    19 MyApp                          0x100d80fa8 main + 30 (MyDatabase.swift:30)
    20 libdyld.dylib                  0x1a7fa2360 start + 4
```

Below is the line where the report says on which the crash has been generated.

```
if let index = cell.array.firstIndex(where: {$0.name == self.name}){
    //code here
}
```

I looked for a lot of solutions out there but couldn't find any right solution for myself.

Thanks!

Comment: It needs all types taking part in crashing line.

Comment: @Asperi Thanks for the response! In the block where the app crashes, I just scroll my collection view vertically using the index I get from that line. Can you please elaborate on your point?